# Angular 17 standalone application integrate CKEditor 5 -- Error: window is not defined

Tags: angular, angularjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

My Angular (version 17.1.2 and standalone) app can not integrate CKEditor.
I have followed the step by step guide [here](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/angular/#code-example).

Error:

```
[vite] Internal server error: window is not defined
      at r (d:/Study/Nam3_HK3/DoAn/bookmanagement/fiction-management-fe/node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/build/ckeditor.js:1:12102)
      at __require2 (D:/Study/Nam3_HK3/DoAn/bookmanagement/fiction-management-fe/.angular/vite-root/fiction-management-fe/chunk-ZLOYPDTO.mjs:51:50)
      at eval (d:/Study/Nam3_HK3/DoAn/bookmanagement/fiction-management-fe/src/app/component/admin-chapter-feature/admin-chapter-feature.component.ts:8:32)
      at async instantiateModule (file:///D:/Study/Nam3_HK3/DoAn/bookmanagement/fiction-management-fe/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-9A4-l-43.js:50861:9) (x3)
```

Here is my code:

```js
import { CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';
import { ChangeEvent } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular/ckeditor.component';
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-chapter-feature',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    CKEditorModule,
    CommonModule,
  ],
  templateUrl: './admin-chapter-feature.component.html',
  styleUrl: './admin-chapter-feature.component.css',
})
export class AdminChapterFeatureComponent {
  public Editor = ClassicEditor;

  public onReady(editor: any) {
    console.log("CKEditor5 Angular Component is ready to use!", editor);
  }
  public onChange({ editor }: ChangeEvent) {
    const data = editor.getData();
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>CHAPTER MANAGEMENT</h2>
<div class="wrapper-chapter">
  <form class="example-form">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <mat-label>Chapter name</mat-label>
      <input matInput placeholder="" />
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <mat-label>Chapter content</mat-label>
      <textarea matInput placeholder=""></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>

    <ckeditor
    [editor]="Editor"
    data="<p>Hello from CKEditor5!</p>"
    (ready)="onReady($event)"
    (change)="onChange($event)"
    >
  </ckeditor>
  </form>
</div>
```

File `typings.d.ts`:

```js
declare module '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic' {
  const ClassicEditorBuild: any;
  export = ClassicEditorBuild;
}
```

My `package.json`:

```json
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^7.0.1",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^41.2.1",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core": "^41.2.1",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine": "^41.2.1",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils": "^41.2.1",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-watchdog": "^41.2.1",
```